# scipy.sparse matrix to xgboost dmatrix conversion: extremely slow

Tags: python, performance, scipy, sparse-matrix, xgboost

I am trying to train a gradient tree boosting model using xgboost in python. For my application I build data batches to feed the model "on the fly". Right now the code is too slow, the bottleneck seems to be the scipy.sparse to dmatrix conversion:

```
type(sparse_batch[0]) #scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
sparse_batch[0].shape #(1035500, 317)

%%timeit -n1 -r1
xgb.DMatrix(sparse_batch[0], feature_names=model_features)
1 loop, best of 1: 1min 31s per loop
```

The same operation with numpy.ndarray matrix seems to be extremely faster:

```
type(dense_batch[0]) #numpy.ndarray
dense_batch[0].shape #(1035500, 317)

%%timeit -n1 -r1
xgb.DMatrix(dense_batch[0], feature_names=model_features)
1 loop, best of 1: 8.08 s per loop
```

I wonder why is that happening, is there something I can do to make the conversion from sparse faster? Unfortunately I can't always initialize from dense arrays since sometimes batches do not fit in memory.

Comment: (1) Read up DMatrix internals and tune your sparse-matrix format (or just try them all) (2) Look at xgboost's issue-tracker as there seems to be some discussion about numpy-dmatrix inefficiency in general (not necessarily your problem as also with dense np-arrays) (3) Mini-batches are probably < 1024; maybe just using the dense ones is ok (worse caching probably) (4) If you are crazy: look up DMatrix internals and write a custom build-method tuned for your spmat